# Incremental write of Protocol Buffer object

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have Protocol Buffer for logging data.

```
message Message {
    required double val1 = 1;
    optional int val2 = 2;
}

message BigObject {
    repeated Message message = 1;
}
```

I receive messages one per second. They stored in memory with my BigObject and they used for some tasks. But at the same time i want to store that messages in file for backup in case application crash. Simple writing BigObject every time will be waste of time. And I trying to find way to write only added messages since last write to file. Is there a way for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protobuf is an appendable format, and your layout is *ideal* for this. Just open your file *positioned at the end*, and start with a new (empty) `BigObject`. Add/serialize *just the new `Message` instance*, and write to the file (from the end onwards).

Now, if you parse your file *from the beginning* you will get a single `BigObject` with all the `Message` instances (old and new).

You could actually do this by logging each individual `Message` as it arrives, as long as you wrap it in a `BigObject` each time, i.e. in pseudo-code

```
loop {
    msg = await NextMessage();
    wrapper = new BigObject();
    wrapper.Messages.Add(msg);

    file = OpenFileAtEnd();
    wrapper.WriteTo(file);
    file.Close();
}
```

Comment: do you mean msg.WriteTo(file); ?

Comment: hmm.. when i did 
`msg->SerializeToZeroCopyStream(output);` 100x times file size was 3800
but when i did
`bigObject->SerializeToZeroCopyStream(output);` file size was 4000
bitObject contain 100 msg's.
so I think we missed something.

Comment: oh. i see, you're right. one bigObject with 10 msg objects in binary format the same as 10 bigObjects with 1 msg each.

Comment: @Evgen exactly; on the wire they are identical